# Убрать переход на строку CKeditor при добавлении ссылки.

Tags: php, ckeditor

Суть проблемы: когда в визуальном редакторе текста CKeditor добавляешь ссылку на выделенный текст, то все то за ссылкой перекидывает на новую строку. 
Как от этого избавиться?
Заранее спасибо.
PS: варианты перехода на что-то другое не предлагать.

Comment: На демо этого не наблюлается http://ckeditor.com/demo#widgets

Comment: А у меня такая проблема наблюдается, к сожалению, но оно переносит не в самом эдиторе а на отображаемой странице.

Comment: Так может проблема не в `ckeditor`, а в серверной части, где обрабатываются данные поступившие от пользователя, в парсере.

Comment: Пробуйте в CSS для ссылок выставить display:inline

Comment: А можно пожалуйста подробнее, куда это вписывать?
Т.е. как указать это свойство глобально для всего?
На сайте через бутстрап все писалось.

Comment: Глобально для всего это может быть не самый лучший вариант, т.к. это затронет абсолютно все ссылки на сайте, включая меню и остальное. Но в принципе надо в .css файле написать `a { display: inline-block; }` myvzar советует сделать ссылку, используя инструменты редактора. Когда создаете ссылку (указываете адрес), там есть вкладка "Advanced". В ней в поле style надо написать `display: inline;` или `display: inline-block;`

Comment: К сожалению предложенные варианты не сработали. На самом предпросмотре все выглядит отлично. А вот когда страница открывается, то там ссылка с новой строки.

Comment: @DaVinchi, вы бы показали кусок html там, где ссылка не так отображается после вывода, люди бы меньше гадали на кофейной гуще.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась небольшим костылем. 
После написания текста добавляем в самое начало в режиме просмотра html(кнопочка "Источник") следующую строку: `<style> a{display:inline;}</style>`
Большое всем спасибо за помощь.